# Jquery fadeIn fadeOut scrolls the page up

Tags: jquery, scroll, responsive-design, fadein, fadeout

I know this question has been asked previously however the solution does not meet my requirements.

HTML

```
<div id="slider" class="contentPanel">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="aliyah creations">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="aliyah creations">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="aliyah creations">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
function fadeContent() {
   $(".contentPanel .content:hidden:first").fadeIn(500).delay(5000).fadeOut(500, function() {
       $(this).appendTo($(this).parent());
       fadeContent();
   });
};

fadeContent();
```

The above code works fine unless you scroll to the bottom of the page and as fadeIn is called it automatically scrolls the page up to the top of the div.

Previously the solution was to set a fixed height of the div however I want the site to respond depending on the screen resolution being used to view it.

Here is the CSS

```
#slider{
    float:left;
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    border-style: none;
    position:relative;
    margin: 0px;
}

.content { 
    float:left;
    max-height:400px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:black;
    background-size: 50% auto;
    text-align:center;
    display: none; 
}

.content img{
    max-width:100%;
}
```

below is a link to the site

(removed link)

Comment: Scrolls most likely due to the fact the page got shorter because the faded image is gone

Comment: Exactly what @Huangism said. Fade will hide a div and show another so it's going to make body smaller then bigger again. You need `.contentPanel` to have a fixed height or a js code to check all `.content img` height and add dinamically a height to `.contentPanel` based on the bigger image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry your site link did not work for me, it just kept loading but I assume this is an image slider type of thing, so:

You could use a placeholder transparent image to fill the space of the faded out image area. Since your site is responsive(maybe). You need to make this placeholder file the same aspect ratio as the images, or make it the same size as the images. So the placeholder image will make sure that the area always has a height. When fading, the content will not get shorter or taller because the placeholder is the same size or same aspect ratio as your other images.

If you use an image with same aspect ratio, then it should have a width of 100% so it extends the width of the container, like your slide show images. This is the implementation I have used, there might be better ways of doing this, but I think this solution is fairly easy, no js needed and only 1 extra image, possibly very small if you are going the aspect ratio way.

Something like

```
<div id="slider" class="contentPanel">
    <div class="content">
        <img src="images/slide1.jpg" alt="aliyah creations">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <img src="images/slide2.jpg" alt="aliyah creations">
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <img src="images/slide3.jpg" alt="aliyah creations">
    </div>
    <div class="placeholder">
        <img src="images/placeholder.jpg" alt="aliyah creations">
    </div>
</div>
```

then apply the same css to the placeholder div and it should work

Comment: Thanks alot! Works fine, not sure why the link doesn't work though :S

Comment: it was taking a long time so I closed the window, it might of worked if I waited longer but I am @ work